# Brinkhoff Generator Esri street shapefile + nodes and edges files

Tags: java

This is the original Brinkhoff generator.: http://iapg.jade-hs.de/personen/brinkhoff/generator/

& this is a modified version for higher workloads: http://moto.sourceforge.net/

The modified version does two things as their website says: 
1) It takes an ESRI shapefile and produces node- and edge files in the format of the Brinkhoff generator.
2) It takes node- and edge files and generates position and query traces.

I tried esri shape files with the node/edge generator and it does not seem to read it, and the node/edge files provided in the original Brinkhoff website does not work with this version as it includes nodes names.

I get this message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No names allowed in nodes!

Does anyone know what esri shape files I can use (and if possible any free downloads?)

How can I remove nodes/edges names from the Brinkhoff  node/edge files?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to remove the names, but I am getting another error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No dense packed node file!

Any source for compatible input files?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Comment: Thank you all and sorry that I have broken a rule; I am new here :)